# How selenium method send keys works?

Tags: java, validation, selenium-webdriver, testing

I am testing a form that creates a new object.
This object is built from integers and string inputs.
In each of the fields, I am trying to test the input of a negative number.
If I type a negative number, the (-) sign is automatically erased (doesn't even show).
If I copy-paste a negative number, it will be shown in the field as is.
If I use the sendkeys method, it works as the copy-paste: negative number is accepted.
Moreover, when I copy-paste a decimal number it is rounded to an integer: 40.72 automatically turns to
41. When I use typing 40.72 it becomes 412. The same for send keys.

How should the send keys method function? As if I am typing? As if I am copy pasting?
Thanks in advance.

I expected of the send keys to imitate typing action (wrong maybe).
The minus should be removed from a negative number.
Results:
Input - (-120):
Typing - (120)
Copy pasting - (-120)
sendkeys - (-120)

Input - 40.72 (should be rounded to closest integer)
Typing - 412
Copy pasting - 41
sendkeys - 412